# Credit Card Icons Missing after Upgrade

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, payment-processor

I upgraded CiviCRM from 5.6.1 to 5.9.0 and later tried 5.10.4.  Both time the credit card icons on our contribution and registration pages were missing after the upgrade (see image).  I had to revert back to 5.6.1 (edit: icons are the same as the security code icon).

I was able to successfully upgrade our test site.  I also copied the production database to the test site (CiviCRM 5.10.4) and ran the database upgrade.  The credit card icons were present.  This tells me that the production database is OK.  What could be wrong?  What should I try next?

We use Wordpress and PayPal Standard.

Added 3/6/2019

I duplicated the problem on a new test site that is a near copy of our production site (copied all the website files and the CiviCRM database).  I noticed that the HTML code for the credit card icons on the malfunctioning contribution page doesn't match that of a good page (see code below).

**Bad HTML Code**

```
<a href="#" title="[object Object]" class="crm-credit_card_type-icon-Visa"><span>[object Object]</span></a>
```

**Good HTML Code**

```
<a href="#" title="Visa" class="crm-credit_card_type-icon-visa"><span>Visa</span></a>
```

[image: Missing Credit Card Icons]

Comment: Clearing the CiviCRM Cache didn't fix it; nor did using a browser that didn't have the site cached.

Comment: hmm sorry to hear that. in the 2 cases where clients hit this it was def. not happening for other users on the same page, hence taking us down the track of the issue being local.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the test site and the Credit Card Icon are now present.  I can't say why.  I upgraded the production site again to 5.10.4 and the icons were present.  I was to make a test-drive contribution on both sites.

There's one remnant of this problem.  When I hover over the credit card icon it says [object Object] instead of Visa, Master Card, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have had this reported on a couple of sites for them, we suspected and it proved to be a local caching issue, in their case with Firefox. I don't presume that is the same issue, but in case it is this could help

https://superuser.com/questions/173210/how-can-i-clear-a-single-site-from-the-cache-in-firefox

Comment: That was after us clearing caches in civi